# umbraco cms I'm confused

Tags: visual-studio, content-management-system, umbraco

I need information.
My company gave me to edit a site created with CMS Umbraco. I opened it with Visual Studio and it works correctly, but if I want to change the code is different from normal just because it has been used Umbraco.

They told me I have to open it directly in the CMS Umbraco. 
I installed it but I can't import the project.
can you help me?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? When you say it works, can you view the site and access the backend of the CMS?

Comment: no I not  access the backend of the CMS, I see only the final site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a bit clearer.

Umbraco is a content management system, if you want to edit content then you will need to be running an instance of Umbraco, you will need to be logged in as an administrator and you will need to publish any changes.

The login URL should be http://yourdomain.com/umbraco

So you shouldn't be importing anything, you just need the site up and running in IIS and a running version of the database.

The Umbraco user forum is a great place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I state that I have never used CMS, I followed the guide and installed Umbraco that opens me a blank panel to create a new site. Now my company has provided me with my site's source code, which I opened in Visual Studio and the db associated with it.
My question is: how do I open the site in my instance of Umbraco? I was formito no admin login. maybe I'm being confused or do not have well understood the operation.